# BackUp Odoo 8 Windows erreur zero size file

Tags: postgresql, odoo, backup, odoo-8

I make a specific development of the db_backup openerp 7 module to running on version 8 Odoo.

So it is properly installed and it does backup
the problem is that the sql file size is zero KB

this is the code  backup_scheduler.py

```
import xmlrpclib
import socket
import os
import time
import base64
from openerp.osv import fields,osv,orm
from openerp import tools, netsvc
from openerp.tools.translate import _
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def execute(connector, method, *args):
    res = False
    try:        
        res = getattr(connector,method)(*args)
    except socket.error,e:        
            raise e
    return res

addons_path = tools.config['addons_path'] + '/auto_backup/DBbackups'

class db_backup(osv.Model):
    _name = 'db.backup'

    def get_db_list(self, cr, user, ids, host='localhost', port='8069', context={}):
        uri = 'http://' + host + ':' + port
        conn = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(uri + '/xmlrpc/db')
        db_list = execute(conn, 'list')
        return db_list

    _columns = {
                    'host' : fields.char('Host', size=100, required='True'),
                    'port' : fields.char('Port', size=10, required='True'),
                    'name' : fields.char('Database', size=100, required='True',help='Database you want to schedule backups for'),
                    'bkp_dir' : fields.char('Backup Directory', size=100, help='Absolute path for storing the backups', required='True')
                }

    _defaults = {
                    'bkp_dir' : lambda *a : addons_path,
                    'host' : lambda *a : 'localhost',
                    'port' : lambda *a : '8069'
                 }

    def _check_db_exist(self, cr, user, ids):
        for rec in self.browse(cr,user,ids):
            db_list = self.get_db_list(cr, user, ids, rec.host, rec.port)
            if rec.name in db_list:
                return True
        return False

    _constraints = [
                    (_check_db_exist, _('Error ! No such database exists!'), [])
                    ]

    def schedule_backup(self, cr, user, context={}):
        conf_ids= self.search(cr, user, [])
        confs = self.browse(cr,user,conf_ids)
        for rec in confs:
            db_list = self.get_db_list(cr, user, [], rec.host, rec.port)
            if rec.name in db_list:
                try:
                    if not os.path.isdir(rec.bkp_dir):
                        os.makedirs(rec.bkp_dir)
                except:
                    raise
                bkp_file='%s_%s.sql' % (rec.name, time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S'))
                file_path = os.path.join(rec.bkp_dir,bkp_file)
                fp = open(file_path,'wb')
                uri = 'http://' + rec.host + ':' + rec.port
                conn = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(uri + '/xmlrpc/db')
                bkp=''
                try:
                    bkp = execute(conn, 'dump', tools.config['admin_passwd'], rec.name)
                except:
                    logger.notifyChannel('backup', netsvc.LOG_INFO, "Could'nt backup database %s. Bad database administrator password for server running at http://%s:%s" %(rec.name, rec.host, rec.port))
                    continue
                bkp = base64.decodestring(bkp)
                fp.write(bkp)
                fp.close()
            else:
                logger.notifyChannel('backup', netsvc.LOG_INFO, "database %s doesn't exist on http://%s:%s" %(rec.name, rec.host, rec.port))

db_backup()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because an error occurs on the backend that does not get propagated back to the client. If you check the server logs at the time you take a backup you will probably see the issue.

**Note** If you need a script to get a backup from or restore a database to a v7, v8 or v9 server take a look at https://github.com/daramousk/odoo_remote_backup

I have developed a script for this specific reason which you can use or change to resolve your issue.